# Hiding a column in pivot table if the column is null in Oracle OBIEE

Tags: oracle, obiee, oracle-analytics

we are creating a pivot table in OBIEE, we need to hide columns from the pivot table if those columns are null. Is there any implicit way of doing this in Oracle OBIEE?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. For the very simple reason that a pivot is a cross-table and does intersections of data so you quite literally can never be sure that a whole "column" as you call it retrieves only NULLs. It simmply doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Is there an option in obiee to hide null columns in a table?

Comment: Same thing: Why would you ever want to do that? Retrieving no results at all and retrieving NULL and retrieving 0 are three different answers. Anybody working with analytics and data should know that. And all 3 answers are valid and mean something specific. In the case of NULLs most likely that the data quality is rubbish and should be tackled.